# Count Filtered Result and Paste Text for Count Amount

Tags: excel, vba

**Goal:** I would like to modify the below code so that instead of copying a range and pasting the filtered range into a column, instead it counts the amount of rows that is filtered for, and using the count, pastes text for the next x amount of rows at the next empty row.

**Example:** I am filtering Loss of Income column, for all non blank results. The result is that there are 10 entries that fit this criteria. I then want in a different sheet ("Calc Data"), to paste "Loss of Income or Rent" for the next 10 empty rows in column C.

**Code:**

```
Dim RPDataTbl As ListObject
Dim DescCol As ListColumn, BI As ListColumn
Dim copyRng As Range

Set RPDataTbl = Sheets("Risk Partner Data").ListObjects("RPdata")
With RPDataTbl
    Set DescCol = .ListColumns("Property Identifier")
    Set BIcol = .ListColumns("Loss of Income or Rent")

    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=BIcol.Index, Criteria1:="<>"
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set copyRng = DescCol.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not copyRng Is Nothing Then
    copyRng.Copy

    With Sheets("Calc Data")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Loss of Income or Rent"
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

RPDataTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=BIcol.Index
```

Tried to edit the code, however it only pastes the special text once, not for the whole range result e.g. if 10, 10 rows in C having "Loss of Income or Rent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `Option Explicit` to the the top of your module. Even better, go to *Tools* > *Options* and click *Require Variable Declaration*. You have an undeclared variable `BIcol` - you declared `BI As ListColumn`.
2. Regarding your main issue, perhaps use the `Count` of `copyRng` within a `Resize`. Note that the following code is revised to match your example: filter the "Loss of Income" column, get the number of non-blank results, and paste "Loss of Income or Rent" in column *C*.

---

```
Sub Test
    Dim RPDataTbl As ListObject
    Dim DescCol As ListColumn, BIcol As ListColumn
    Dim copyRng As Range

    Set RPDataTbl = Sheets("Risk Partner Data").ListObjects("RPdata")
    With RPDataTbl
        Set DescCol = .ListColumns("Property Identifier")
        Set BIcol = .ListColumns("Loss of Income or Rent")

        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=BIcol.Index, Criteria1:="<>"
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Set copyRng = BIcol.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not copyRng Is Nothing Then
        With Sheets("Calc Data")
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(copyRng.Count).Value = "Loss of Income or Rent"
        End With
    End If

    RPDataTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=BIcol.Index
End Sub
```